# ViewCompat.enableAccessibleClickableSpanSupport(textview) is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, accessibility, talkback

I am giving `ViewCompat.enableAccessibleClickableSpanSupport(textview)` a try but spannable is crashing the app still. The way I have this is

```
// ViewCompat.enableAccessibleClickableSpanSupport(textview) 
val ss = SpannableString(someString)
ss.setSpan( bla bla bla) // i have a clickablespan with nocopyspan and imagespan
textview.text = ss
textview.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
ViewCompat.enableAccessibleClickableSpanSupport(textview)
```

I tried having the ViewCompact code at the top and at the bottom, one at the top or one at the bottom but still my app is still crashing on Accessibility or Talkback. I am running the app on Android 9 but I think it will crash in all devices anyway. ANyone has the similar experience and how do you approach this? I could have use html way but I need the part of the textview to be clickable and navigate to the next fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe NoCopySpan may be the root of your issue. Try removing that from your custom ClickableSpan implementation. Unfortunately, then you may deal with the possible memory leaks from using ClickableSpan. You could also disable the accessibility for that specific TextView. See
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setImportantForAccessibility(int)

So I think your options are:

1. Remove setting the Clickable span altogether, and just separate your text into several TextViews with the clickable text all in one TextView. (Drawback is creating more views than necessary)
2. Remove implementing the NoCopySpan interface in your custom ClickableSpan implementation (but at the risk of possibly memory leaks with ClickableSpan)
3. Continue implementing NoCopySpan, and applying your custom span, but call setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO) or via the XML attribute, but this TextView won't support accessibility anymore. Also, it's not guaranteed the accessibility service will respect this attribute setting.